# How do I avoid warnings about c++Future-extensions when using feature test macros and Clang?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, clang++, suppress-warnings

I have some code targetting C++14 which could make use of C++17's `[[nodiscard]]` attribute. It seemed natural to me to use feature-test macros to accomplish this:

```cpp
#ifdef __has_cpp_attribute
#   if __has_cpp_attribute(nodiscard)
#       define NODISCARD [[nodiscard]]
#   else
#       define NODISCARD
#   endif
#else
#   define NODISCARD
#endif

struct NODISCARD SomeType {};
```

However, [Clang "helpfully" warns me that I'm using a feature that doesn't exist until C++17](https://godbolt.org/z/rff9vx):

> ```
> <source>:12:8: warning: use of the 'nodiscard' attribute is a C++17 extension [-Wc++17-extensions]
> struct NODISCARD SomeType {};
>        ^
> <source>:3:28: note: expanded from macro 'NODISCARD'
> #       define NODISCARD [[nodiscard]]
>                            ^
> 1 warning generated.
> Compiler returned: 0
> ```

This is quite annoying, as I have appropriately verified that the C++17 feature exists even if we're compiling in C++14 mode. I don't want to turn off `-Wc++17-extensions`, but I need to suppress this particular case of the warning.

Is there a good way to use feature-test macros with Clang that avoids these warnings?
Or is there a good way to suppress the warnings just for these cases where I've verified that it's okay?

Comment: Perhaps something with _Pragma? Would also require detecting if the compiler is clang, because compilers warn on "unknown pragmas." Also doesn't help for other compilers which might emit similar warnings.

Comment: Check also cpp version `__cplusplus`?

Comment: @Jarod42 If the compiler supports a C++17 feature even when compiling on C++14 mode, I would prefer to still use the feature, because the feature gives better diagnostics for my users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can temporarily disable diagnostics with the pragma `clang diagnostic`:

```cpp
#ifdef __has_cpp_attribute
#   if __has_cpp_attribute(nodiscard)
#       ifdef __clang__
#           define NODISCARD \
                _Pragma("clang diagnostic push") \
                _Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Wc++17-extensions\"") \
                [[nodiscard]] \
                _Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")
#       else
#           define NODISCARD [[nodiscard]]
#       endif
#   endif
#endif

#ifndef NODISCARD
#    define NODISCARD
#endif

struct NODISCARD SomeType {};
```

Comment: I haven't been able to come up with something better. Although this alone is insufficient, because compilers annoyingly warn on unknown pragmas, so the `_Pragma` also needs to be guarded to only exist when compiling with Clang. This is quite poor user experience of feature test macros.....